# SQL Developer Accents Encoding

Tags: encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper, special-characters

Hello I am building a simple export script, but the path has accents (special characters) ´~ç`

How can I force SQL Developer to use the correct encoding?

```
set feedback off
set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF'
set nls_lang=PORTUGUESE_PORTUGAL.WE8ISO8859P1 
set echo off
set encoding UTF-8
set SQLFORMAT csv

column dcol new_value SYSDATE 
column dest new_value VARCHAR2
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY') dcol from dual;
select 'Y:\Operação Logística\' dest from dual;
```

Results:

```
"DCOL" 
"04-06-2018" 
"DEST" 
"Y:\OperaÃ§Ã£o LogÃ­stica\"
```

Comment: are you using SQLcl or SQL Developer.? cause this works for me in SQL Developer select 'Y:\Operação Logística\' dest from dual; -- i have a display font selected that supports those characters

Comment: Well i need it working in sqlcl, but it doesn't work in my SQL Developer

Comment: mmm, it's the set sqlformat csv that's borking it

Comment: hmm.. not here, removing the sqlformat csv achieves the same result

Comment: can you start a thread here please https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer - trading comments here will get old, quick